# Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have a batch file which I am calling from C++ using `system("name.bat")`. In that batch file I am trying to read the value of a registry key. Calling the batch file from C++ causes `set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\stuff` to fail.

However, when I directly run the batch file (double clicking it), it runs fine. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Batch file:

```
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ansoft\Designer\2014.0\Desktop
set VALUE_NAME=InstallationDirectory
REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME%
```

C++ file:

```
int main(void)
{
    system("CALL C:\\HFSS\\setup_vars.bat");
    return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE 1:

I found out that the key is actually in the 64-bit registry, and I was building my C++ solution as a 32-bit. Once I fixed that, it found the registry key fine.

Now I am having an issue adding that path to my **PATH** variable. Instead of creating a system variable, it is creating a user variable **PATH** and adding it there.

Running from command line works.

Code:

```
set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Ansoft\Designer\2014.0\Desktop\
set VALUE_NAME=InstallationDirectory

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME%`) DO (
   set ValueName=%%A
   set ValueType=%%B
   set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
   @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
   @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)

:: Set PATH Variable
set path_str=%PATH%
set addPath=%ValueValue%;

echo %addPath%
echo %ValueValue%

echo %PATH%| find /i "%addPath%">NUL

if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   SETX PATH "%PATH%
) else (
   SETX PATH "%PATH%;%addPath%;" /M
)
```

---

UPDATE 2:

I moved the placement of the option /M and it is now adding to right **PATH** variable.

However, when I am doing this, it is adding the **PATH** more than once (3 times) and then it is also adding a path to visual studio amd64 folder.

I'm mot sure why that is happening.

Comment: Did you run it from the command line exactly as you've stated? `C:> CALL C:\HFSS\setup_vars.bat`? Don't leave out the "CALL" in your testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) creates a copy of the entire environment table of the process starting a new process for the new process. Therefore on start of your C++ application, your application gets the environment table including **PATH** from parent process, *Windows Explorer* or in your case *Visual Studio*. And this **PATH** is copied for `cmd.exe` on start of the batch file.

Taking the entire process tree into account from Windows desktop to the batch file, there have been several copies made for **PATH** and some processes perhaps appended something to their local copy of **PATH** like *Visual Studio* has done, or have even removed paths from **PATH**.

What you do now with `SETX PATH "%PATH%` is appending the local copy of **PATH** modified already by the parent processes in process tree completely to system **PATH** without checking for duplicate paths.

Much better would be to throw away all code using local copy of **PATH** and instead read the value of system **PATH**, check if the path you want to add is not already in system **PATH** and if this is not the case, append the path you want to add to system **PATH** using `setx`.

And this should be done without expanding the environment variables in system **PATH** like `%SystemRoot%\System32` to `C:\Windows\System32`.

---

Here is the batch code required for your task tested on Windows XP SP3 x86, Windows 7 SP1 x64 and Windows 11 22H2.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "KeyName=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Ansoft\Designer\2014.0\Desktop"
set "ValueName=InstallationDirectory"
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "%KeyName%" /v "%ValueName%" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%G" == "%ValueName%" (
        set "PathToAdd=%%I"
        if defined PathToAdd goto GetSystemPath
    )
)
echo Error: Could not find non-empty value "%ValueName%" under key
echo        %KeyName%
echo(
endlocal
pause
exit /B

:GetSystemPath
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
        set "SystemPath=%%I"
        if defined SystemPath goto CheckPath
    )
)
echo Error: System environment variable PATH not found with a non-empty value.
echo(
endlocal
pause
exit /B

:CheckPath
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem The folder path to add must contain \ (backslash) as directory
rem separator and not / (slash) and should not end with a backslash.
set "PathToAdd=!PathToAdd:/=\!"
if "!PathToAdd:~-1!" == "\" set "PathToAdd=!PathToAdd:~0,-1!"
if "!SystemPath:~-1!" == ";" (set "Separator=") else set "Separator=;"
set "PathCheck=!SystemPath!%Separator%"
rem Do nothing if the folder path to add without or with a backslash
rem at end with a semicolon appended for entire folder path check is
rem already in the system PATH value. This code does not work with
rem path to add contains an equal sign which is fortunately very rare.
if not "!PathCheck:%PathToAdd%;=!" == "!PathCheck!" goto EndBatch
if not "!PathCheck:%PathToAdd%\;=!" == "!PathCheck!" goto EndBatch
set "PathToSet=!SystemPath!%Separator%!PathToAdd!"
set "UseSetx=1"
if not "!PathToSet:~1024,1!" == "" set "UseSetx="
if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe set "UseSetx="
if defined UseSetx (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "!PathToSet!" /M >nul
) else (
    set "ValueType=REG_EXPAND_SZ"
    if "!PathToSet:%%=!" == "!PathToSet!" set "ValueType=REG_SZ"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v Path /t !ValueType! /d "!PathToSet!" >nul
)
:EndBatch
endlocal
endlocal
```

The batch code above uses a simple case-insensitive string substitution and a case-sensitive string comparison to check if the folder path to append is present already in system **PATH**. This works only if it is well known how the folder path was added before and the user has not modified this folder path in **PATH** in the meantime. For a safer method of checking if **PATH** contains a folder path see the answer on [How to check if directory exists in %PATH%?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046515/1012053) written by [Dave Benham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham).

**Note 1:** Command `setx` is by default not available on Windows XP.

**Note 2:** Command `setx` truncates values longer than 1024 characters to 1024 characters.

For that reason the batch file uses command `reg` to replace **system PATH** in Windows registry if either `setx` is not available or new path value is too long for `setx`. The disadvantage on using `reg` is that [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message is not sent to all top-level windows informing Windows Explorer running as Windows desktop and other applications about this change of system environment variable. So the user must restart Windows which is best done always on changing something on persistent stored Windows system environment variables.

The batch script was tested with **PATH** containing currently a folder path with an exclamation mark and with a folder path being enclosed in double quotes which is necessary only if the folder path contains a semicolon.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `setx /?`