# How to run a batch file in an another shell seamlessly

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013

I have this build file:

```
@echo off
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat
echo Deleting old exe...
del build_win32\dist\bin\OgreApp_d.exe
cd build_win32
echo Building As Debug
msbuild /detailedsummary /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /t:build ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
echo Done building, Exiting.
cd dist\bin\
start OgreApp_d.exe
cd ../../../
```

And to run it I run from cmd `build`.  The problem is that  since I do not exit cmd between builds, the `PATH` grows and grows because of `"%VS120COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat` until it refuses to run because path is too long. Is there a way I can start this in another shell but in the same place.

I could do

```
start cmd.exe /K "build.bat"
```

but it opens a new window and it is more complicated than just `build`

Comment: Have you tried `setlocal`? (Type `setlocal /?` for more information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice of [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) is very good and very easy to apply:

```
@echo off
setlocal
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat
echo Deleting old exe...
del build_win32\dist\bin\OgreApp_d.exe
cd build_win32
echo Building As Debug
msbuild /detailedsummary /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /t:build ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
echo Done building, Exiting.
cd dist\bin\
start OgreApp_d.exe
cd ../../../
endlocal
```

A new local copy of the environment variables table is made with command [setlocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal). All changes on environment variables are done now on this local copy instead of the environment variables of always running command line interpreter process. The temporary local table of the environment variables is deleted by command [endlocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/endlocal). So value of **PATH** is not growing and growing on every execution of this batch file.

By the way: **vsvars32.bat** is obviously coded poorly as it does not check on current **PATH** if a folder path to add is not already included in **PATH**. My answer on [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) contains the few code lines to check **PATH** for a folder path to add before appending it to **PATH**.