# How to set PATH environment variable in batch file only once on Windows?

Tags: batch-file

I have batch file that sets user path and is run as part of Visual Studio IDE build step.

```
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO %PATH%
set COMSPEC = "%VCINSTALLDIR%\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
setx PATH "..\..\lib\libsndfile;..\..\lib\simulink" 
@ECHO %PATH%
```

When I build the project, close VS, and reopen it, and rebuild, I see
appended path as part of `PATH` variable. However, I see that in Windows setting of environment variable `PATH` variable is created under user environment variables as

```
..\..\lib\libsndfile;..\..\lib\simulink
```

**Question 1:**

Why does this path also appear as appended path as part of system environment variable?

On executing `echo %PATH%` through Visual Studio console (when I run the project second times) prints system variable path and the new path I created appended to it.

**Question 2:**

I want to modify my batch file so that it only sets once `PATH` environment variable in user settings during first run of Visual Studio build. If the user variable `PATH` already exists on subsequent runs, it should not execute **set** command again to avoid appending new path again and again in system variable.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**edit:** After some testing, it appears that my original answer isn't entirely applicable to OP's questions.  To answer OP more directly:

1. `%PATH%` combines the values in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path` with `HKCU\Environment\Path`.  When you `setx "dir;dir"`, what you're setting is the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` `Path` value.  The machine-wide `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` `Path` value remains untouched.  That's why you see your values as appended, rather than as replacements.  You'd have to use `setx /m` to replace the `HKLM` `Path` value.  **But please don't unless you want to create severe problems with your operating system installation.**
2. If you want to test whether a directory exists in `%PATH%`, you could `cd` or `pushd` both to the directory you want to check and to each directory within `%PATH%` to unify each, making sure all relative paths, environment variables, etc. are flattened.  `set "var=%CD%"` for each.  Then `if /I "!dir1!"=="!dir2!"` the directory already exists somewhere in `%PATH%`.  There's an example of this in my original answer below.

The reason my original answer isn't entirely applicable is because `setx` itself isn't as destructive as I once thought.  The danger is that often times when users want to append a directory to their path, they'll `setx /m PATH "%PATH%;new dir"`; and that *is* destructive.  Because `%PATH%` is expanded before `setx` writes the value, all the directories in PATH are expanded prematurely.

The following method would be safer:

```js
set "env=HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

for /f "tokens=2*" %%I in (
    'reg query "%env%" /v Path ^| findstr /i "\<Path\>"'
) do setx /m PATH "%%J;new directory"
```

But that wasn't really what OP asked, and I apologize for the knee-jerk answer.

---

**original answer:** `setx` is destructive and shouldn't be used this way.  When you `setx PATH` you're converting the registry value data type from REG_EXPAND_SZ to REG_SZ.  As soon as you do this, all the dynamic environment variables stored in your %PATH% get converted to flat, absolute paths.  Use the `path` command to append directories to your `%PATH%` temporarily, and `reg add` to do so permanently.  (As a side note, there's also `dpath`, which temporarily adds a directory to your path, but can only be used by the `type` command.  Scroll 2/3 the way down [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) for more info on `dpath`.)

Here's a utility script I wrote to add directories to my `%PATH%` in a less destructive manner.  It will also avoid adding the same directory to `%PATH%` more than once, regardless of how it's formatted (e.g. trailing backslash, relative paths, environment variables, or any other permutation).

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not exist "%~1" goto usage

for %%I in ("%~1") do pushd "%%~I" 2>NUL && (set "new=!CD!" && popd) || goto usage
for %%I in ("%PATH:;=";"%") do pushd "%%~I" 2>NUL && (
    rem // delaying expansion of !new! prevents parentheses from breaking things
    if /i "!new!"=="!CD!" (
        echo !new! already exists in %%PATH%%
        goto :EOF
    )
    popd
)

call :append_path "%new%"

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 "dir"
goto :EOF

:append_path <val>
set "env=HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
for /f "tokens=2*" %%I in ('reg query "%env%" /v Path ^| findstr /i "\<Path\>"') do (

    rem // make addition persistent through reboots
    reg add "%env%" /f /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%J;%~1"

    rem // apply change to the current process
    for %%a in ("%%J;%~1") do path %%~a
)

rem // use setx to set a temporary throwaway value to trigger a WM_SETTINGCHANGE
rem // applies change to new console windows without requiring a reboot
(setx /m foo bar & reg delete "%env%" /f /v foo) >NUL 2>NUL

color 4E
echo Warning: %%PATH%% has changed.  Reopen the console to inherit the changes.

goto :EOF
```

Comment: I called the above script that you gave with one of the paths. First  time, it gave 'Warning: %%PATH%% has changed.  Reopen the console to inherit the changes' .Next time, calling it with same argument did not give the message "already exists in path" but rather same path was added twice. This happened both from command prompt and VS pre build event call.

Comment: @user915783 I just happened to think, the script might need to be run with elevation.  Can you try running it as administrator and see whether you have better luck?

Comment: Hi rojo. I added your script to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator) and sure it does print that path is added.but,if I go into registry and look into added paths, and I can't find those under "PATH" variable anywhere.in fact . I can't find those paths anywhere. So, where are the paths? second, when I ran the script from VS IDE prebuild event as **call setdllpathSafe.bat "..\..\lib\libsndfile" & call setdllpathSafe.bat "..\..\lib\simulink"**, it prints current path thrice before giving mssg?

Comment: @rojo Which version of __setx__ changes type of registry value from `REG_EXPAND_SZ` to `REG_SZ`? After reading your answer, I wanted to adapt [my batch solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) for this task. But I tried first my batch code once more with looking on type of registry value `Path` before and after batch execution on Windows 7 SP1 x64 using __setx__ with file version 6.1.7600.16385. But the registry value type was unchanged `REG_EXPAND_SZ` after every modification. In could see in Process Monitor that __setx__ first queries `Path` and then sets it with right type.

Comment: @Mofi same version.  Go to `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and create a new `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value, call it "foo" and set its data to "bar".  Leave that window open, but open a console window and do `setx /m foo bar`.  Now go back to the Registry Editor window and refresh.  `foo` is now type `REG_SZ`.  But I do see that if I do `setx /m foo %bar%` (where `%bar%` is not defined), setx sets the data type back to `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.  I forget where I read about the destructive nature of `setx`, but I've never actually experimented with it until now.

Comment: I suppose all one needs is to make sure all the variables in `%PATH%` stay collapsed when appending directories to it using `setx`.

Comment: @rojo, well analyzed and explained. Type of registry value depends on value of variable. `REG_EXPAND_SZ` is used by __setx__ with value of variable containing `%...%` otherwise the type is `REG_SZ`.

Answer (score 1):

1. That what Setx does. See `Setx /?` where it tells you this. It adds it to the user's environment permanently (unless /m is used). However %PATH% is built from system and user environment's PATH (and also autoexec.bat on 32 bit windows and if started through ShellExecute also App Paths reg key))
2. Don't worry about. Setx doesn't add paths to %PATH% if they already exist in %PATH%.

Why are you redefining the system variable %COMSPEC%.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I was redefining  so that subsequent path addition would take place successfully from within Visual Studio. Although Your answer 2 solves my problem, but just out of curiosity, is there a way to remove portion of appended path from %PATH% next time a batch file is run?

Comment: You can certainly do it with `reg` command and `wmic` by reading editing and writing back what you want. The problem is windows (which means explorer) won't know it changed till a logoff/on. But you could use `reg` to delete and `setx` to put back. `Setx` sends a system change event to programs that monitor it and explorer rebuilds it's path, so any program it starts (like CMD) will have new path.