# mysql install from batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am tring to use this to install mysql from the command line

```
cls
echo off

SET ProgFiles86Root="%ProgramFiles(x86)%"

IF NOT %ProgFiles86Root%=="" ( SET ProgFiles86Root=%ProgramFiles% )

echo Starting MySQL install
msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.11-win32.msi" /qn

echo MySQL installed successfully

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"%ProgFiles86Root%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER 

DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo MySQL has been installed successfully

setx PATH "%%ProgFiles86Root%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin%;"

cd /
c:

mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';"


mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'192.168.0.%' IDENTIFIED BY '123abc' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH 

PRIVILEGES;
```

But i get the error

```
Starting MySQL install
MySQL installed successfully
Configurating MySQL Server...
The system cannot find the path specified.
MySQL has been installed successfully

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The command line says Mysql was installed, but it wasnt, as i cannot fined it in the uninstall section in control panel

Comment: Isn't it `"Program Files" with a space? Also why are you doing the 32-bit version?

Comment: I got the same error even when I added space as you suggested. I am installing on a 64bit system, and since i dont know which platform it would be installed by the end user

Comment: What do you mean "end user?" What's the intended goal here? If you're writing an installer there are specialized tools for that and I'd strongly encourage you to use one. They make undoing whatever changes you've made quite easy.

Comment: I am making and installer that will be redistributed to different clients, I have tried inno setup without success. It installed successfully, but it failed to create the database from inno, dont know why as the debugger kept returning 1 as exit code

Comment: At the absolute least use the [Windows Installer developer toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185688(v=vs.85).aspx). Do not try and do this with hacked together batch files. Your clients will not be happy. Most installer kits can run system commands as necessary, but those aren't required as often as you'd think if you're just making directories and moving files around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake 1:** Assigning program files folder path with and without double quotes to `ProgFiles86Root`

This line

```
SET ProgFiles86Root="%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
```

assigns the string `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%"` with the double quotes and all possibly existing trailing spaces and tabs to environment variable `ProgFiles86Root`.

The **IF** condition in line

```
IF NOT %ProgFiles86Root%=="" ( SET ProgFiles86Root=%ProgramFiles% )
```

works because the value of the environment variable `ProgFiles86Root` is with double quotes. The double quotes are also compared by command **IF**, not just the strings enclosed by the double quotes.

But if this **IF** condition is true because of batch file is running on a 32-bit Windows, the value of environment variable `ProgramFiles` is assigned to the environment variable `ProgFiles86Root` without double quotes.

For more details on how to assign a string correct to an environment variable see the answer on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) and also the answers linked there.

Let us next look on:

```
"%ProgFiles86Root%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe"
```

This is either expanded for example on 64-bit Windows to

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)"\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe"
```

with double quotes inside a double quoted file name with path which is of course not good, or for example on 32-bit Windows to

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe"
```

which would be a correct specification of the executable.

**Mistake 2:** Invalid command line in batch file

The next mistake is on line:

```
DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3306 Charset=utf8
```

This line does not contain a command to execute for Windows command interpreter and therefore must result in an error message.

I'm quite sure that this line contains options for the `mysqlinstanceconfig.exe` command line. The same mistake is made on last line of batch code in question with the string `PRIVILEGES;` which should be at end of the command line above.

**Mistake 3:** Attempt to *REPLACE* **user** PATH with a custom folder path

The command `setx` is for *REPLACING* **user** (as done here) or **system** PATH (only with option `/m` which of course requires administrator privileges) and does not have any effect on **local** PATH of currently running command process interpreting the commands in the batch file.

It is of course a very bad idea to *REPLACE* the **user** PATH by the string you specified on the `setx` command line although there is by default no **user** PATH defined. This computer could start not working anymore as expected if this attempt to replace the **user** path would be successful.

It looks like you want to just append the path to directory `bin` of MySQL Server 5.5 to **local** PATH to run the executable `mysql` without path. But why not running `mysql.exe` with full path?

**Mistake 4:** Setting a different current directory is done wrong

```
cd /
c:
```

The first line does nothing. To set current directory to root of current drive it would be necessary to run `cd \` as the backslash character is the directory separator on Windows and the forward slash is for options. The command **CD** interprets the slash as beginning of an option and therefore ignores it as there is no option specified after the forward slash. Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` for help on this command.

The second line makes the current directory on drive C: the current directory for the currently running command process. Which directory is the current directory on drive C: is not defined by this code.

**Mistake 5:** Attempt to run `mysql.exe` without path and file extension

The command `setx` hopefully for all users failed although this is very unlikely. But even if `setx` is successful, the current command process interpreting the batch file has already its local **copy** of all environment variables from parent process created on starting the batch file. Therefore running `mysql` without file extension and path must fail, except MySQL was already installed before and its directory `bin` was already added to **system** or **user** PATH before the batch file processing started.

**Solution:**

Use this batch code:

```
@echo off
cls

if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" (
    set "MySQLServerPath=%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
) else (
    set "MySQLServerPath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
)

echo Starting MySQL install ...
%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /i "mysql-5.5.11-win32.msi" /qn
echo MySQL installed successfully.

echo Configurating MySQL Server ...
"%MySQLServerPath%\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3306 Charset=utf8
echo MySQL has been configured successfully.

cd /D C:\

rem if not "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" set "PATH=%PATH%;"
rem set "PATH=%PATH%%MySQLServerPath%"

"MySQLServerPath\mysql.exe" --user=root --password=mysql -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';"
"MySQLServerPath\mysql.exe" --user=root --password=mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'192.168.0.%' IDENTIFIED BY '123abc' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

The path to directory for MySQL binaries is not added to **system** PATH by this batch code if not done on installation or configuration of MySQL. If for some unknown reason the **local** PATH must be extended with path to MySQL binaries directory, uncomment the two lines near end of batch file above by removing the command **REM** from both lines.

But if you really want to add MySQL binaries directory to **user** or **system** PATH which I really don't recommend then read very carefully the comments and answers on

- [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915767/)
- [How can I use a .bat file to remove specific tokens from the PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656375/)
- [How to check if directory exists in %PATH%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344/)