# What is the reason for nodemon working in cmd but not in a batch file?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, npm, cmd, nodemon

I am in the process of making a discord bot. All of the code that I have written for the bot works except for the batch file that is supposed to run it. Originally I was just using the `node` command and when I opened cmd, navigated to the folder, and typed it manually it worked fine, but when I put that same code into a batch file it gave me this error:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This is all the code for that batch file:

```
@echo off
node bot.js
pause
```

The node command was in my path so I'm not sure why it wasn't working, but in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028607/), someone recommended that instead of typing just `node` to type the full file path, so I tried this and it worked.

Here is the new working code:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" bot.js
pause
```

Then I installed **nodemon**. Again this works in the cmd when I navigated to the folder and typed it manually, but when I try to do it in the batch file it does not work. Instead of giving me the error it had been before the window just instantly closes. Here is that code:

```
@echo off
nodemon bot.js
pause
```

Since I have the pause command at the end of the code it should stop there if I get an error, but it is closing before it gets there for some reason. The `nodemon` command is in my path and I have also tried replacing `nodemon` with the file path, `C:\Users\tdkni\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd`, like I was recommended in the previous post. Neither of these solutions worked, and I think that is because there is some other problem besides the `nodemon` command not being detected. I don't see any error message since it is closing instantly so I don't know exactly what is wrong.

The registration of the file extensions `.bat` and `.cmd` is as follows according to an advice in a comment deleted in the meantime.

Comment: open cmd.exe, then run the script from there, it will show you where the issue is. Do not double click the batch file.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did, I opened cmd, went to the folder, and i typed the name of my batch file and it worked perfectly, but when i double click it it just closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank all of you for trying to help me with this problem I was having. You have all been very helpful, and while it may not have fixed my problem it did help me understand how all of this works. I just tried to start the bot using the batch file I made and it suddenly worked. I don't know why because I tried to start it the same way I had been the entire time, but as far as I could find, no one else was having this issue anyways so it probably won't matter much that I don't know what fixed it. Again, thank you to everyone that helped me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is pretty clear why `node.exe` was not found by `cmd.exe` in directory `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

**Local** `Path` being **system** and **user** `Path` concatenated contains `"C:\Program Files\nodejs;"` instead of just `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Folder paths in `Path` should be never enclosed in double quotes with one exception: The folder path itself contains one or more `;`. In this case the folder path with `;` must be enclosed in double quotes to get the semicolon(s) in folder path not interpreted as separator between the folder paths. That is general CSV syntax as described on Wikipedia article [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which is used by Windows for the folder paths in `Path` with using semicolon as separator.

For that reason `cmd.exe` searches in a folder with name `C:\Program Files\nodejs;` for `node.*` with a file extension listed semicolon separated in environment variable `PATHEXT`. But there is no folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs;` because the folder is `C:\Program Files\nodejs` without the semicolon at end.

And also `PATHEXT` is defined wrong as it contains at end the folder path `C:\Program Files\nodejs` although it should contain only file extensions separated by a semicolon.

Other small mistakes:

1. The first 4 folder paths in **system** `PATH` should be always:

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
   ```

   Some installers add folder paths at beginning of folder paths list instead of appending them at end as it can be seen here. The Intel64 compiler and the Oracle Java folder paths should be moved in **system** `PATH` after PowerShell folder path.
2. Folder paths can but should not end with a backslash. All backslashes at end of a folder path should be removed from **system** and **user** `PATH`. Microsoft added since Windows Vista the PowerShell path with a trailing backslash for some unknown reason. But it is safe and recommended to nevertheless remove the backslash after `WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`.
3. **System** and **user** `Path` (if latter is existing at all) and also `PATHEXT` should not end with a semicolon. There should be no `;` after last folder path respectively last file extension as this means according to CSV specification that there is one more value (folder path, file extension) which is an empty value.

I recommend to define **system** `Path` with following value respectively folder paths:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%ProgramFiles%\nodejs;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit
```

I recommend to define **user** `Path` with following value respectively folder paths:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%AppData%\npm
```

Those two folder paths are user account related and should be added for that reason to **user** and not **system** `Path`.

I recommend to fix **system** environment variable `PATHEXT` to:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
```

For more details about usage of `Path` and `PATHEXT` see the answer on [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) Please take also a look on Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer to the original question, for the benefit of other Windows users (Linux/Mac users not my problem).

In essence, user is trying to run some script.js file with nodemon;

```
C:\path\to\my\project>nodemon bot.js
```

, and wants to put in a batch file.

If nodemon is installed globally -g, it installs under

```
C:\Users\<YourLogin>\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd
```

So your batch file should be

```
cd C:\path\to\my\project\
%AppData%\npm\nodemon.cmd bot.js
PAUSE press any key to exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try for us please, if it works, I will explain:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\tdkni\AppData\Roaming\npm"
echo Testing Script > OUTPUT.log
nodemon.cmd bot.js >> OUTPUT.log
pause
```

Comment: if you run it from cmd.exe, what is the output? does it show you the pause?

Comment: Well in the bot.js file it is just a loop so it never really gets to the pause unless there is an error. Instead of showing the pause it will just start the bot and I can close the window if I want to stop it. The pause is really only there to show an error if one happens, but it is not showing it. When I try to run it from cmd the bot just starts up as it is supposed to.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. How do you call it in `cmd`? give me the exact string. also, where exactly is this batch file of yours located?

Comment: I go to the folder using `cd\Users\tdkni\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot`. Then I use the command `"run_nodemon,bat"`. run_nodemon.bat is the script that contains this:
@echo off
    nodemon bot.js
    pause

Comment: it is not possible that it does not work if you placed that code in there. If you run it from cmd and it works, then it must work on double click.. Please try the edited code. It should echo to file. double click it, let it run, in the same directory will be a file called OUTPUT.log.. please see the contents of it. and if the file actually exists after double click

Comment: I tried that and it is still closing immediately, and there is no output file. I really don't understand why I am having this problem or the one in the previous post since as far as I can tell I have done everything correctly.

Comment: Then you are not running the same file. Please take my code. Create a file called. Gerhard.cmd and add the code. Double click gerhard.cmd and get back to.me with the result.

Comment: I made a new file called Gerhard.cmd and it still closed instantly. Could it be that there is a problem with my installation of nodejs and I should try reinstalling it?

Comment: No. Put pause before echo off and  double click again

Comment: It did do the pause before echo off

Comment: Then check for the output log in "C:\Users\tdkni\AppData\Roaming\npm"

Comment: The output log was in there but all it said was `Testing Script`

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is older but I faced the same issue today. If someone like me stumbled across, based on joedotnot's answer, here is what it fixed for me.

```
devserver.cmd
@echo off
echo Auto Starting Development Server
cmd /k "cd x:\cmdproxy & config\env.cmd & %AppData%\npm\nodemon.cmd"
```

Where `X:` is the development folder on the VM Host System mapped as Network Drive in the development Guest System. And `config\env.cmd` is another batch file which holds some env settings.

My server file is named `index.js` so there was no need to add is as argument. Nodemon finds the file automatically.