# How to use SetX to append a variable to the Windows PATH (NOT the value of the variable)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file running under Windows 8 and Server 2012 R2 where I append a variable to the `PATH`. The problem is when I use `setx`, it adds the VALUE of the variable to the path instead of adding the variable itself.

Example: (These of course are not real, only for this example)

My path is `C:\Windows`
My variable `%VAR_1%` is set to `C:\Windows\system32`

If I type in this command:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%";"%VAR_1%" /M
```

then what I would expect my `PATH` to be:

```
C:\Windows;%VAR_1%;
```

But instead the `PATH` becomes:

```
C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;
```

So the issue is the `setx` command is adding the value of the variable, instead of the variable itself to the `PATH`.  I've searched on this site (and others), and I've not found the answer to this.

Is there a way to do this with `setx`?

I've heard there are other tools that can be used for this, but I need to do this with whatever built in tools Windows 8 / Server 2012 R2 has because I would be pushing this batch file to hundreds of computers and I don't want to have to send each user little tool as well.

Comment: Double your percent signs (`%%VAR_1%%`).

Comment: @RyanBemrose, setx.exe allows using `~` to represent `%`, but this is completely the wrong tool to modify `Path`, at least using the current `%Path%` value. It'll make a mess of things -- expanding values that were originally `%` variables and combining the system and user `Path` values.

Comment: @DOSGUY Please read the answer on [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564). Never use __local__ `PATH` to extend __system__ `PATH`. The __local__ `PATH` is a combination of __system__ `PATH` and __user__ `PATH` with all environment variables in both `PATH` already expanded. So what you do is corrupting __system__ `PATH`.

Comment: @DOSGUY Other Stack Overflow topics which should be read by you completely (question, all answers, all comments) before further processing on your batch coding task for modifying __system__ `PATH`. [How to search and replace a string in environment variable PATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648362) [How can I use a .bat file to remove specific tokens from the PATH environment variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656375/) [How to set PATH environment variable in batch file only once on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885906/)