# adding directory to path environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, environment-variables

My requirement is to add one of the directory to ***path*** environment variable in windows at the time of installing my application and remove the same from ***path*** environment variable at the time of uninstallation using batch file.

In one of the stackoverflow answer related to this suggested the following to add a directory to path environment variable.

```
setx path C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\
```

It is adding to path variable but when I try to add one more, it overwrites the existing value which I have added. How to avoid this?

How to remove the directory path which I have added from path environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the existing value of it like this:

```
setx PATH %PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\
```

To remove it you could probably do something like this:

```
setx PATH=%PATH:;C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\=%
```

Which would substitute the path it was given with nothing to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user's part of `path` variable is empty, e.g. for adding a directory as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_apppath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\"

set "_keyBase=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"   machine
set "_keyBase=HKCU"                                                    user

set "_dataTyp="
set "_dataOld="
for /F "tokens=2,*" %%G in (' 
  reg query "%_keyBase%\Environment" -V path ^| findstr /I "\<path\>"
  ') do (
      set "_dataTyp=%%G"
      set "_dataOld=%%H"
)
if defined _dataOld (
    set "_dataNew=%_apppath%;%_dataOld%"
) else (
    set "_dataNew=%_dataOld%"
    set "_dataTyp=REG_SZ"
)
rem debugging output: show script variables
set _

if /I "%~1" EQU "write" (
    reg add "%_keyBase%\Environment" -V path -T %_dataTyp% -d "%_dataNew%" -F
) else (
    rem debugging output
    ECHO reg add "%_keyBase%\Environment" -V path -T %_dataTyp% -d "%_dataNew%" -F
) 
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Note that I use `reg add` instead of [`setx` command](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html). See also [this Rojo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889785/3439404) for exhaustive explanation.

**Output**.

```
d:\bat> D:\bat\SO\42140086.bat
_apppath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\
_dataNew=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;D:\bare!;D:\Remote
_dataOld=D:\bare!;D:\Remote
_dataTyp=REG_EXPAND_SZ
_keyBase=HKCU
reg add "HKCU\Environment" -V path -T REG_EXPAND_SZ -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;D:\bare!;D:\Remote" -F

d:\bat> D:\bat\SO\42140086.bat write
_apppath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\
_dataNew=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;D:\bare!;D:\Remote
_dataOld=D:\bare!;D:\Remote
_dataTyp=REG_EXPAND_SZ
_keyBase=HKCU
The operation completed successfully.

d:\bat> D:\bat\SO\42140086.bat
_apppath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\
_dataNew=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;D:\bare!;D:\Remote
_dataOld=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;D:\bare!;D:\Remote
_dataTyp=REG_EXPAND_SZ
_keyBase=HKCU
reg add "HKCU\Environment" -V path -T REG_EXPAND_SZ -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\;D:\bare!;D:\Remote" -F

d:\bat>
```

Above output shows that the only check if a key is empty does not suffice as running it twice would add the same directory twice as well.

However, checking if a `path` key  (user or machine-wide) contains a particular directory is not such simple task. For instance, some entries in `path` contain a trailing `\` backslash while others don't. Moreover, some entries in a `path` registry value of `REG_EXPAND_SZ` could be *tangled* in other environment variables e.g. `%ProgramFiles%\SomeApp` instead of `C:\Program Files\SomeApp` etc.

The following complex script `TestPath.bat` could help to analyse Windows `path` environment variables (note that it could show incorrect values if a path contains an exclamation mark `!` due to [enabled delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)):

```
@ECHO OFF
set "HkcuEnv=HKCU\Environment"
set "HklmEnv=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo --- %date% %time% %~nx0 %*  

if /I "%~1" EQU "dir" (
    set path
    Call :printPath path "" dir %~2
    echo/
    echo tested using the following findstr regex: 
    echo "%pathext:;=$ %$"
    ENDLOCAL
    goto :eof
)

set pathext

Call :duplicity pathext
  
Call :printPath path ""

Call :duplicity path

set "HKCU_type="
set "HKCU_path="
for /F "tokens=2*" %%G in (
  'reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path 2^>NUL ^|findstr /I "path"'
  ) do (
    set "HKCU_type=%%G"
    set "HKCU_path=%%H"
  ) 
Call :printPath HKCU_path %HKCU_type%
if /I "%HKCU_type%"=="REG_EXPAND_SZ" Call :printPath HKCU_path %HKCU_type% Expanded

set "HKLM_type="
set "HKLM_path="
set "qqqq=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
for /F "tokens=2*" %%G in ('reg query "%qqqq%" /v Path^|findstr /I "path"'
  ) do (
    set "HKLM_type=%%G" 
    set "HKLM_path=%%H" 
  ) 
Call :printPath HKLM_path %HKLM_type%
if /I "%HKLM_type%"=="REG_EXPAND_SZ" Call :printPath HKLM_path %HKLM_type% Expanded

echo/
pause
REM echo/
REM set HK
echo/
echo/Usage: %~nx0
echo/       %~nx0 dir
echo/       %~nx0 dir all
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:printPath
echo/
echo %~0 %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4
if "!%~1!" NEQ "" (
  set "ggg="!%~1:;=" "!""
  rem set "ggg=!ggg:\"="!"
  for %%G in (!ggg!) do (
    if /I "%~3" NEQ "expanded" (
        if /I "%~3" EQU "dir" (
            set "_partpath=%%~G"
            if not "%~4"=="" ( 
                echo/
                echo "%%~G"
                if /I "!_partpath:%SystemRoot%=!" EQU "%%~G" (
                    dir /B /A:-D "%%~G" | findstr /I "%pathext:;=$ %$"
                    echo errorlevel !errorlevel!
                    if errorlevel 1 pause
                    rem timeout /T 3 /NOBREAK >NUL
                ) else (
                    >NUL (dir /B /A:-D "%%~G" | findstr /I "%pathext:;=$ %$")
                    echo errorlevel !errorlevel!                system default
                    if errorlevel 1 pause
                )
            ) else (
                if NOT "%%~G"=="" (
                    for /F %%g in ('
                      2^>NUL dir /B /A:-D "%%~G" ^| findstr /I "%pathext:;=$ %$" ^| find "." /C
                    ') do echo "%%~G" %%g file(s^)
                ) else (
                    echo "%%~G" ? file(s^)
                )
            )
        ) else (
            echo "%%~G"
        ) 
    ) else (
        call echo "%%~G"
    )
  )
)
goto :eof

:duplicity
echo/
echo %~0 %~1 %~2
set /A "ii=0"
set "ggg="!%~1:;=" "!""
set "ggg=!ggg:\"="!"
for %%G in (!ggg!) do (
  set /A "ii+=1"
  set /A "jj=0"
  for %%g in (!ggg!) do (
    set /A "jj+=1"
    if /I "%%~G"=="%%~g" if !ii! LSS !jj! echo !ii!, !jj!: %%~g 
  )
)
goto :eof

REM TODO: unfinished procedure / incorrect output
:deflatePath
echo/
echo %~0 %~1 %~2
set "ggg="!%~1:;=" "!""
rem set "ggg=!ggg:\"="!"
set "NewPath="
for %%G in (!ggg!) do (
  set "item=%%~G"
  set "meti="
  call :deflateItem "ProgramFiles(x86)"
  if defined meti (
    rem echo # !item!
  ) else (
    call :deflateItem "ProgramFiles"
    if defined meti (
      rem echo # !item!
    ) else (
      call :deflateItem "SystemRoot"
      if defined meti (
        rem echo # !item!
      ) else (
        rem echo = !item:%%=%%%%!
      )
    )
  )
  if defined NewPath (
    set "NewPath=!NewPath!;!item!"
  ) else (
    set "NewPath=!item!"
  )
)
echo !NewPath!
rem reg delete HKCU\Environment /v NewPath /f
rem setx NewPath "!NewPath!"
rem WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
rem reg query HKCU\Environment /v NewPath|findstr /I "NewPath"
goto :eof

:deflateItem
  set "meti=!%~1!"
  if "!meti!"=="!item!" (
    set "item=%%%~1%%"
  ) else (
    set "meti=!item:%meti%\=!"
    if "!meti!" == "!item!" (
      set "meti="
    ) else (
      set "item=%%%~1%%\!meti!"
    )
  )
goto :eof
```