# Python subprocess cannot process len(env["PATH"]) > 8191

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, popen

I am writing tool that use `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.Popen`, but faced with an issue on Windows 10 that when `env["PATH"]` variable exceed size 8191~8192 characters `subprocess` cannot find program located in `env["PATH"]`:

```
`cmake` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Looks like `CreateProcess` on Windows that is used underhood do not parse such long `env["PATH"]`

I have found lots of similar issues on internet and looks like it is restriction on Windows with maximum command line length, but unfortunately I have not found how to fix it ...

Have somebody faced with the similar issue ?

Is there a way to modify registry to increase this max length ?

Or do you know about some kind of workaround to fix it on Windows except of removing some paths from `env["PATH"]` ?

Comment: Can you work around by supplying the absolute path to `cmake`?

Comment: Yes, there is *Windows PATH variable size limit* (you can google for the emphasized string). Maybe that there is some duplicity in your `PATH` variable. Check e.g. as follows: `y = [x.rstrip('\\') for x in os.environ["PATH"].split(';')]; len(y); len(set(y))` - and/or there are some entries of no use (some installers/uninstallers does not purge the `PATH` properly). Check e.g. using my [`TestPath.bat` script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42148234/3439404) (its usage see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1527258/376602)).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you don't have any problem invoking whatever command from the command prompt, but you do within Python. How about `Popen(..., shell=True)`? Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Windows, so these suggestions are just a shot in the dark. The first suggestion is to use the absolute path to `cmake` as I stated in the comment.

The second is to use `shutil.which()` to locate the path to `cmake` and use that:

```py
import shutil

cmake_path = shutil.which("cmake")
assert cmake_path is not None, "It seems shutil.which could not find cmake"

# Use cmake_path in subproces, instead just "cmake"
```

Comment: It is not possible, because I use command that underhood use cmake, cmake is used not by me