# Append to System PATH variable value using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, environment-variables

I want to create a batch file to add the current directory to my System variable `PATH`,  *(not my User variable)*.

When I use:

```
SETX /M PATH "%CD%;%PATH%"
```

it does the needed thing. However, I get an error message:

> data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

When I check the System variable using the GUI, I saw that User Path is getting added to the System Path. As a result, the System Path has duplicated entries.

I tried assigning the `%PATH%` variable to a temporary variable and echoing but I saw the duplications there as well.

I saw in some stack answer that the `%PATH%` variable we use in the batch file is actually a concatenation of both User Path and System Path.

At the Command Prompt, I tried:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH"
```

but I don't have idea much about whether we can use it to take that PATH value and assign to another variable.

1. So I need to find a way to assign ONLY the SYSTEM PATH to a temporary variable, let's say SYS_PATHS. How can I do that?
2. Is there a better way to overcome this scenario?

Comment: You might not believe it, but others wanted to add a folder path also to system path using a batch file. So lots of solutions can be found on using Stack Overflow search for example with [\[batch-file\] system path add](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+system+path+add). There are lots of __not__ good solutions which tend to corrupt __system__ `PATH` and some very good solutions.

Comment: Here are some of my solutions: [Adding the current directory to Windows path permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080452/3074564), [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) and [How to search and replace a string in environment variable PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650324/3074564) and [How can I use a .bat file to remove specific tokens from the PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664286/3074564) There is a lot to read, but please read it.

Comment: Use the registry key, instead!

Comment: Please take also a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It looks like you don't need current directory path added persistent to __system__ `PATH`. You just want to add this folder path to __local__  `PATH`. This is usually not needed because of `cmd.exe` searches first always in current directory for a program or script before making use of __local__ `PATH` and __local__  `PATHEXT`.

Comment: So it could be enough to use in batch file just `if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" ( set "PATH=%PATH%%CD%" ) else ( set "PATH=%PATH%;%CD%" )` to __append__ current directory path to __local__ `PATH` environment variable not persistent stored in Windows registry and being used only by currently running command process and all applications started from within this command process.

Comment: @mofi, yes, usually cmd.exe and `CreateProcess` (without an explicit application path) search the working directory. CMD searches there first, whereas a generic `CreateProcess` call searches the application directory (i.e. `%__APPDIR__%`) before the working directory. However, if we define an environment variable named "NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath" with any value, then they do not search in the working directory unless the name has a backslash in it (e.g. "\spam\eggs.exe").  A "." entry can be added to the end of the system or user "Path", which is more secure but still convenient.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I know because of your comment on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) resulting in chapter __H) Is it possible to disable file search in current directory?__ But I am quite sure that this environment variable is used only on Windows servers but not on Windows clients as nearly no batch file would work anymore with this environment variable defined.

Comment: @Mofi, I always define this environment variable on my systems, but I add "." back explicitly to the end of the user "Path", so the working directory is still searched. It's just the last directory searched. Anyway, almost always I use ".\" to refer to a file in the working directory.

Comment: Thank you all for helping out. I found the answer I was looking for in one of the links provided by @Mofi. I'll add the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the question I asked in a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885906/how-to-set-path-environment-variable-in-batch-file-only-once-on-windows) provided by @Mofi. This is how you can take the system path only, and append a directory to it.

```
set "env=HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

for /f "tokens=2*" %%I in (
     'reg query "%env%" /v Path ^| findstr /i "\<Path\>"'
) do setx /m PATH "%%J;%CD%"
```