# setting environment variable if not present using batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012

I am trying to set an environment variable in case it is not present and if it is present the script will just exit. I am trying it with this following code.

```dos
@echo off
echo %machine% > c:\machineoutput.txt
findstr /I /c:"C:\Oracle\Ora12c\perl\bin" c:\machineoutput.txt
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    goto SETPATH
) else (
    EOF
)
:SETPATH
setx /m machine "%oracle_home%\perl\bin;%path%"
:EOF
exit
```

But some how it's not working as it should. I am able to set the variable but even if the variable exist it sets it again and then goes to exit.

Please help me in finding out what is that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: why do you `goto SETPATH` in the first branch but only `EOF` without going anywhere in the else branch?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc this batch file is being called from another batch file so if the path exist , this batch file will get terminated and the parent batch file from where this was being called will resume it's operation.So i am going to EOF in this  file if path exist if not it wil set the path.

Comment: no, EOF is not a valid command and you'll get error. If you want to go the toe EOF label, use `goto EOF`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why is checked if `C:\Oracle\Ora12c\perl\bin` exists in *non standard* environment variable `machine` for determining if `%oracle_home%\perl\bin` should be added to the system environment variable **PATH**. I suggest checking system **PATH** for existence of this directory path.

`EOF` is no valid command. The *Windows Command Processor* outputs therefore an error message and continues with next command line being the line with `setx`. That is the reason for batch code posted in the question is not working as expected. The command in **ELSE** branch should be `goto :EOF` or `exit /B`.

Much better would be following code which checks if `%oracle_home%\perl\bin` or its expanded equivalent exists in system **PATH** and **appends** instead of prepends it to system **PATH** if not existing in system **PATH**.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%oracle_home%\perl\bin\*" exit /B
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
        set "SystemPath=%%I"
        if defined SystemPath goto CheckPath
    )
)
echo Error: System environment variable PATH not found with a non-empty value.
echo(
endlocal
pause
exit /B

:CheckPath
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PathToAdd=%%oracle_home%%\perl\bin"
set "OraclePerlPath=!oracle_home!\perl\bin"
if "!SystemPath:~-1!" == ";" (set "Separator=") else set "Separator=;"
if "!SystemPath:%PathToAdd%=!" == "!SystemPath!" (
    if "!SystemPath:%OraclePerlPath%=!" == "!SystemPath!" (
        set "PathToSet=!SystemPath!%Separator%!PathToAdd!"
        set "UseSetx=1"
        if not "!PathToSet:~1024,1!" == "" set "UseSetx="
        if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe set "UseSetx="
        if defined UseSetx (
            %SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "!PathToSet!" /M >nul
        ) else (
            set "ValueType=REG_EXPAND_SZ"
            if "!PathToSet:%%=!" == "!PathToSet!" set "ValueType=REG_SZ"
            %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v Path /t !ValueType! /d "!PathToSet!" >nul
        )
    )
)
endlocal
endlocal
```

For details on this batch code read the answer on [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) which is used as template for this batch code. It explains also why the batch code in the question is definitely not good at all.

**Note 1:** Command `setx` is by default not available on Windows XP.

**Note 2:** Command `setx` truncates values longer than 1024 characters to 1024 characters.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?` and `reg add /?` and `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `setx /?`