# Batch: How to Prepend the PATH Environment Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

In Windows, the registry entry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path` contains the contents of the `PATH` environment variable.  In my case, the `PATH` environment variable is of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, with the contents:

```
%SOME_PATH%\bin;C:\Windows
```

In addition, I have a user environment variable named `PATH`, which is defined as:

```
%PATH%;C:\Users\Me\Bin
```

If I type `ECHO %PATH%` on the command line, the output is:

```
C:\Some\Path\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Users\Me\Bin
```

OK, now for the desired result given the above scenario.  I want to permanently prepend the machine's `PATH` variable from within a batch script.  After the change, I want all newly opened command windows to pick up my change without the need to log off or restart, and the aforementioned registry value should be changed to:

```
C:\My\Path;%SOME_PATH%\bin;C:\Windows
```

Searching the web on how to do this yields the following approaches:

```
1) SETX Path "C:\My\Path;%Path%" /m

   Result: C:\My\Path;C:\Some\Path\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Users\Me\Bin

   The first problem with this is that it expands the %SOME_PATH% environment
   variable to it's corresponding value.  The second is that %Path% expands
   to include the user's Path variable.

2) REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"^
       /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\My\Path;%%B" /f

   Result: C:\My\Path;%SOME_PATH%\bin;C:\Windows

   The registry value ends up being correct, but I have to log off or
   restart to pick up the changes.
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do from within a Batch file?

Comment: The easiest way to do this from batch is to modify the registry using `reg add` and then call `setx` to change a dummy environment variable.  When the dummy change is broadcast, Explorer reloads the environment table, including the change to PATH.

Comment: I strongly recommend not prepending your folder path, but appending your folder path. Only bad written installers and malware applications prepend a folder path to PATH which could easily result in lots of applications and batch scripts not working anymore if `%SystemRoot%\System32` is not first folder path anymore in system PATH depending on which executables and scripts the prepended folder path contains. See answer on [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) for an example on how to append a folder path to system PATH.

Comment: @Mofi Unfortunately, Cygwin is installed on the target computers.  Two of the applications I need to add to the path are *Perl* and *PostgreSQL*, both of which are included in the Cygwin install.  Since I know appending the paths won't work in this instance, I decided to prepend instead.  I'm also not happy about it, but I can't figure out a reliable way to insert my paths just before the Cygwin entry.  There is no way to know if the path entry will be "C:\Cygwin\bin" or "%CW_DIR%\bin", since it isn't actually installed software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by *@Harry Johnston* in his comment, the solution is to call `SETX` on a dummy variable after changing the registry value.  In my case, the code changed to:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"^
   /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\My\Path;%%B" /f
SETX OS "%OS%" /M
```

I verified that the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) message does NOT include the name of the environment variable that was changed, so a client (such as explorer) that processes that message must refresh all environment variables when it is received.  Proof is that the message only contains two parameters, `wParam` and `lParam`, which are set as follows when changing environment variables:

> *wParam*
>   When an application sends this message, this parameter must be NULL.
>   *lParam*
>   To effect a change in the environment variables for the system or the user, broadcast this message with lParam set to the string "Environment".

Comment: I tried this and it set my path to _litterally_ "C:\My\Path;%%B" the %%B didn't get expanded into anything. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: I must have had the code in a for loop, which wasn't posted as part of my question.  You have to get the registry key prior to updating the variable, so you will need to call `REG QUERY` in a for loop to populate the value into a named variable.  In this case, the named variable is `%%B`.