# How to print/echo windows environment variables such as PATH without interpreting variables?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, echo

Say for example in Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced System Settings > System Properties > Advanced Tab > Environment variables...

I have the following PATH:

**Value 1:**

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;e:\Groovy\GROOVY~1.0\bin;E:\Python;C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;%PYTHON3_HOME%;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;
```

when in cmd, I do:

```
echo %PATH%
```

then I get:

**Value 2:**

```
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;e:\Groovy\GROOVY~1.0\bin;C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;E:\Program Files\Python\Python36-32;E:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.6.0\bin;
```

Then what command in cmd will be able to print out same exact PATH values with variable names (%JAVA_HOME% etc.) as from the System Properties (**Value 1**)?

Comment: The __local__ `PATH` in a running command process contains the folder paths always with environment variable references expanded. The variable expansion is done already by Windows before starting `cmd.exe`. See [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) for an example how to retrieve the __system__ `PATH` directly from Windows registry using `reg query`.

Comment: Please take also a look on [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set <variableName>` command shows variables without interpreting the content.
Or you can ise delayed expansion for that, too.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !path!
```

but in your case, the expansion in `echo %path%` will not expand any further percent parts in the content of PATH (you get only problems with other characters like `&|<>`)

The content is already expanded after you set the path with `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

When you set the percent part instead of the expanded version, then the `PATH` searching doesn't work anymore, as cmd.exe would try to search in the literal path of `%JAVA_HOME%`

To get the *definition* of the PATH from the System Properties can be retrieved from the registry via `REG QUERY`.

User variables with

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v path
```

And the system variables with

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v path
```

Answer (score 0):

From cmd, try this :

```
powershell gci env:<name_variable>
```

Example : `powershell gci env:Path`

If you want all variables name starting (or finishing) with Path just add `*` after (or before) your variable name.

Example : `powershell gci env:*Path*`

:-)